# Grouping hard to reproduce bugs

Tags: manual-testing, bug-report, debugging, bug-advocacy, repro-steps

Many testers come across bugs that are difficult to recreate. They are occasionally reported, and sometimes they are not. This also happens on my team.

I was thinking of making an epic, or a JIRA tag, or some other means of collecting the problems in one place, so that the next time someone encounters a similar bug, instead of wondering if they saw a ghost, they can look through the category and see if something similar has already occurred. Hopefully, the most recent incidence of the bug will provide additional information, allowing the repro steps to be pinpointed.

Do you have any prior experience with something similar? What are the potential disadvantages?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an epic makes sense here. You can certainly use it though. My suggestion is to use Jira labels/tags.

Labels/tags can be applied across multiple teams and projects. They are easily searchable. Epics make more sense to group items on a per team/per project basis.

Are you going to just audit and report on hard to reproduce bugs? Use labels/tags.

Or are you going to have a project, bug bash cycle to address these hard to reproduce bugs? Use epics.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I wasn't aiming directly at bug fixes, more at bug visibility. If Tester A finds a non-reproducible bug and logs it somewhere with some details when Tester B runs into it again, they can add some more details, and hopefully, we will be able to zero in to exact repro steps.

Answer (score 1):

Now a days most of the companies providing security testing services are using labels i.e (intermittent Issue or One time issue) to tag the defects that are hard to reproduce. Further you can create a filter for this label and share it with the team so that every team member can have access to it and check about these issues before reporting any duplicate issue.